# How create a shortcode with html

Tags: shortcode

I want to create a shortcode for following HTML content:

i want print different alert or messages using that

HTML code

```
<div class="notify"><span class="symbol icon-fact"></span> <strong>THIS IS TITLE !</strong>
MY HTML CONTENT HERE
</div>
```

Desirable print on text editor

```
[st_highlight mstyle="notify"  ICON="symbol icon-star" title="THIS IS TITLE" ]
MY HTML CONTENT HERE
[/st_highlight]
```

[image]

after using shortcodes i able to change manually on text editor **div** ,**icon and title** using css class 
for example when i put like below through shortcodes

```
[st_highlight mstyle="notify_red"  ICON="symbol icon-question_marks" title="" ]
    MY HTML CONTENT HERE
    [/st_highlight]
```

[image]

finally i able to generate different style with different css class ,
i try to use below html directory on wordpress text editor but some tags are not supported that's why i want to create shortcode based style editable alert or messages codes

```
<div class="notify"><span class="symbol icon-star"></span> <strong>THIS IS TITLE</strong>

<ul>BELOW ARE ONLY SAMPLE HTML CONTENT 
<li>WHATEVER CONTENT</li>
<li>WHATEVER CONTENT</li>
<li>WHATEVER CONTENT</li>
<li>WHATEVER CONTENT</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You’ve rejected an answer that is correct because they did not read your mind to understand what you *actually* want to do. Please update your question with the full information.

Comment: yes ! ,now i try to explain with more information

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code

```
 function html_show($atts) {

   $makearr =  explode(",",$atts['content']);
   if(isset($makearr) && !empty($makearr)) { 
   foreach($makearr as $arrval){
    $stringli .= '<li>'. $arrval.'</li>';
   }
   } else {
   $stringli = '';
   }  
    $htmlcode = '<div class="notify"><span class="symbol icon-fact"></span> <strong>A kind of a notice box !</strong><ul>'.$stringli.'</ul>
</div>';
    return $htmlcode;
}
add_shortcode( 'htmltag', 'html_show' );


  /*******Using method*******/
echo do_shortcode('[htmltag content="message1,message2,message3,message4"]');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for quick reply ,but after span tag rest of things are variable ,actually i want to create different types of alert or messages like this https://rawgit.com/aviaryan/4125787eaec46348268e/raw/7e2dfdc223f9d3adf08e97355c5756f3ad8c7692/css-box-noimage.html